# Value for date keeps returning NaN

Tags: javascript, date

I want to have a variable having the current date as 'YYYY-MM-DD' format in Javascript. But when i execute my code and check it in the console.log. It simply says NaN

```js
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
console.log("the date format here is ", + date);
```

The console.log shows the output like "the date format here is  NaN"

Can anyone say what have is wrong here?

Comment: `date` is a **String** like `"2019-05-17"` ... `+"2019-05-17"` is not a number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just :

```
console.log('the date format here is ', date);
```

There is no need for '+'

If you are thinking of using string concatenation using the plus operator, `+`, the right syntax would be

```
console.log('the date format here is ' + date);
```

However, when it comes to the scenario you are facing, I would personally perfer ES6's [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
console.log(`the date format here is ${date}`);
```

Comment: @ObitoUchiha You are welcome! I have included other possible ways you can achieve the desired result!

Answer (score 1):

You're using both a comma operator (for argument separation) and a plus operator. Use one:

```
console.log("the date format here is " + date);
```

Or the other:

```
console.log("the date format here is ", date);
```

Comment: _"You're using both a comma operator and a plus operator"_. The comma operator is used between expressions and returns the last operand. But here there is no comma operator. Its just a syntax of passing argument to function

Comment: Look at the OP's code @MaheerAli - there is a comma and a plus, which is invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes but that comma is not comma operator.

Comment: I don't think a comma is ever an operator. It's a punctuator that separates items (identifiers or expressions) in a list. In this case, a parameter list that is passed to a function (*console.log*) and becomes an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in passing the parameters to `console.log()`. You are passing two arguments to function and trying to covert second one which is `date` to `Number` using Unary Plus `+`

```
console.log("the date format here is ", + date);
```

Should be

```
console.log("the date format here is " + date);
```

You can use an array with contains methods as strings and then call them using `map()` and then `join()` them by `-`

```js
var today = new Date();

 var date = ['getFullYear','getMonth','getDate'].map(x => today[x]()).join('-')
 console.log("the date format here is " + date);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the + sign or the, from its wrong

```
console.log("the date format here is ", + date);
```

Here is the correct one

```
  var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    console.log("the date format here is ",  date);
```

[image]